# Know file size with a base64 string

Tags: stream-processing

I do not have very clear what a base64 string is or how it is related to a file.

Right now I have a website that uploads an image as a base64 string to my server. This string is converted back into a bitmap and resized.
However, I would like the least amount of memory to be consumed in my server, therefore I would like to restrict the file size of the images being uploaded without processing them.

Is there a way to know the file of a size without actually saving the file into an stream?

Answer (score 19):

You can calculate the file size (in bytes) using below formula:

```
x = (n * (3/4)) - y
```

Where:

**1**. x is the size of a file in bytes

**2**. n is the length of the Base64 String

**3**. y will be 2 if Base64 ends with '==' and 1 if Base64 ends with '='.

You can read the algorithm here [Base 64 wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding)

Answer (score 10):

Edit: apologies for blatantly wrong info. Acording to this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), it will be a bit larger:

> Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to 1.37 times the original data size + 814 bytes (for headers).

You can use `ContentLength` property of the request to determine what the size is in bytes, although if you are uploading more then one image, it might be trickier.

Comment: To help clarify this answer: Each character in a base64 string represents 6 bits, and each of those characters is 8 bits/1byte. So if you know the size of your headers, the size of the image will be `(contentLengthBytes - headerLengthBytes) * 6 / 8`

Comment: i thought the 6:8 ratio would make sense, but then if 8/6=1.333, where does 1.37 come from?